# How to call shortcode function directly and pass $atts

Tags: plugins, shortcode

I am using the [Media Library Categories](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-library-categories/) plugin. It does not have much documentation, so I have concluded the way to implement it would be using the shortcode `[mediacategories categories="6"]`.

I want to implement this directly into the theme template. So I have tried:

```
<?php if(function_exists(do_shortcode('[mediacategories categories="6"]'))) { ?>
  <h1>Inspiration</h1>
<?php
  do_shortcode('[mediacategories categories="6"]');
}
```

I also tried to implement the function directly, but could not pass the $atts correctly for the function to use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`do_shortcode()` just parses the string. You have to use `echo` or `print` to print it out.

`function_exists()` expects a string that matches a function name. After looking at the plugin, I would try this code:

```
<?php
if ( function_exists( 'mediacategories_func' ) )
{
?>
<h1>Inspiration</h1>
<?php
    print mediacategories_func( array( 'categories' => 6 ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually add a section like this to my shortcode callbacks:

```
if (is_array($atts)) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'primary_att' => 'primary_default',
            ...
        ), $atts));
} else {
    $primary_att = $atts;
}
```

This enables you to pass a 'primary' attribute (replace `primary_att` with whatever you primary attribute is called) directly into the function, without wrapping it in an array...in your case it could be 'categories' and you could call it like `mediacategories_func(6);` then.