# Using WordPress as a document library

Tags: media-library

I would like to include a "resources" section in a new WordPress site I'm creating. I was looking for a document library plugin for WP, and amazingly, couldn't find anything that would work for the simple task of presenting a list of categories, and then displaying uploaded documents in those categories so they could be downloaded.

I could make a resources list by hand, making all the document links myself. But isn't there a better way? You can't even add categories to media library items. I thought about making a blog post for each document, putting those in categories, and then putting a link to the document in the body. But that seems too complicated as well, and I would have to write a special display page myself.

Anyone have advice about how to build a document library using WordPress?

Comment: I've had this need twice now, it astounds me that there's no plugin to yet do this in WP.

Comment: @aendrew You could write one

Answer (score 3):

I use the [Media Library Categories](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-library-categories/) plugin to add categories. It does a wonderful job of adding category functionality, but the code could be improved upon and custom implementation requires some knowledge of PHP, as it only provides you with a shortcode and no documentation.

This [Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10149/how-to-call-shortcode-function-directly-and-pass-atts), maybe be able to help you if you choose this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that custom post types might be your best solution. Create a custom post type for the documents, then they stay out of your regular blog posts, and you can organize them however you see fit.

Comment: That seems like an excessive amount of work for something that could be accomplished through simply creating a new category...

Answer (score 0):

A general download manager will do this job quite well; the best I've run across so far is [WordPress Download Monitor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/download-monitor/).

For more options, see: http://www.wpmayor.com/posts/plugin-reviews/best-document-and-file-management-plugins-for-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have checked out Posts Table Pro, which does everything that you are asking. I have used it on a number of sites and the developer has even created a useful guide that shows you how to use it to make a document library: [How To Create A WordPress Document Library](https://barn2.co.uk/wordpress-document-library-plugin/). Hopefully this some help to yourself and/or anyone else who are stuck with the same issue :-) Thanks, Michael.