# Image Manager Plugin

Tags: plugins, images, gallery

I'm looking for a simple plugin that allows me to manage groups of images. Wordpress does this, but you would need to link the gallery to a page or post. Since i'm looking to create a site banner with dynamic images, i don't want to link a gallery to an specific page.

Is there a good image manager plugin for this simple task or do you know a way to do it natively in wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the [Media Library Categories](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-library-categories/) plugin to add categories. It does a wonderful job of adding category functionality, but the code could be improved upon and custom implementation requires some knowledge of PHP, as it only provides you with a shortcode and no documentation.

This [Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10149/how-to-call-shortcode-function-directly-and-pass-atts), maybe be able to help you if you choose this solution.